# Bin photos by time taken

Tags: python, camera, exif

I have a set of 5 cameras that operate independently of each other. I need to bin the photo's into a groups of 5 images, taken within say a 1 second window. 
I have access to the exif tags and can identify the image capture time.

What is the best way to do it ? A psuedo-python code solution is preferred.

Eg.Input:

```
Cam1 = [002.jpg, 003,jpg, 008.jpg ...]
Cam2 = [005.jpg, 023,jpg, 081.jpg ...]
Cam3 = [014.jpg, 013,jpg, 009.jpg ...]
Cam4 = [011.jpg, 034,jpg, 049.jpg ...]
Cam5 = [001.jpg, 056,jpg, 081.jpg ...]
```

Expected output:

```
Grouped = [[002.jpg, 023.jpg, 013.jpg, 049.jpg, 056.jpg], ......]
```

Here the elements of `Grouped[0]` all have the same time time stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the difference between the capture time and a defined starting time in seconds and put the images in a dictionary with that key.

```
image_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

for image in images:
    # Will return float
    diff = (capture_time - starting_time).total_seconds()

    image_dict[int(diff)].append(image)
```

Then you can convert it to your preferred format:

```
final = []
for key in sorted(image_dict.keys()):
    final.append(image_dict[key])
```

Comment: thanks very much @parchment. I implemented this scheme & used python's date time object to handle the time.